# How to center the first column of equations in two columns?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, align, subequations, alignat

I have a set of subequations that I've arranged into two columns using `alignat`, but currently the subequations are centered on the page. Is there a way of centering the first column of equations, so that the second column is shifted to the right?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{subequations}
\begin{alignat}{2}
\bigcup\nolimits_{i=1}^{k} S_i &= \mathcal{I}, & \label{eqn:allpacked}\\[3pt]
S_i \cap S_j &= \emptyset &\quad &\forall \hspace{1mm} i, j \in \{1, 2,\dotsc,k\}, \hspace{1mm} i \neq j, \label{eqn:nointersect}\\[3pt]
S_i &\in \mathcal{F} & &\forall \hspace{1mm} i \in \{1,2,\dotsc,k\}.\label{eqn:feasible}
\end{alignat}
\end{subequations}
```

[image]

As you can see, the subequations are centered on the page, but I'd like to find a way of centering the first column which are the main equations.

Comment: Can you provide a compatible code with document class and the necessary packages? See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228. In addition, here are some related questions: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Aligning_equations_with_amsmath or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the ambient `gather` (Into your code there are missed `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`). I hope to have understood your question. The look seems better to me than the previous one. Please let me know what you think.

`mathtools` is a larger package of `amsmath` than I've deleted.
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
\begin{gather}
\bigcup\nolimits_{i=1}^{k} S_i = \mathcal{I}, \label{eqn:allpacked}\\[3pt]
\mkern 100mu S_i \cap S_j = \emptyset, \quad \forall i, j \in \{1, 2,\dotsc,k\}, \, i \neq j, \label{eqn:nointersect}\\[3pt]
S_i \in \mathcal{F}, \quad \forall \,i \in \{1,2,\dotsc,k\}.\label{eqn:feasible}
\end{gather}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```